# Importing Data from Login Required Websites to Excel using VBA macros

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I want to ask the question above, I've looked all over the internet but found nothing. I also have tried to use the excel Get & Transform Data From Web, but it can't import anything as it required login.
I have tried to use

```
Sub Go_to_Website()

Dim ie As Object

 

Set ie = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")

 

ie.navigate "http://emonitoring.pu.go.id"

 

ie.Visible = True

 

While ie.Busy

 DoEvents

Wend

 

End Sub
```

but it only opens the web.

How to login to the web, and get the linked data from the website to excel so that it can be updated frequently in the excel? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Such tasks can be done by web scraping techniques. Therefore you also need basic knowledge of html. Your linked login site also contains a captcha, so it is much harder or even impossible to login. Maybe there is a official api interface to get this data of this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this performing direct html code to the site.
This might not apply to your site, but might be a start.

```
 Set user_ieo = .document.getelementsbyname("user_ieo") '
 user_ieo.Item(0).value = "login"

 Set pass_ieo = .document.getelementsbyname("pass_ieo") '
  pass_ieo.Item(0).value = "password"
 .document.forms(0).Submit

Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
                Sleep 500
                DoEvents
            Loop
```